# How to select only char variables with PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
PROC SQL INOBS=10 OUTOBS=10;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.FREQUENCY_&ColumnName AS 
   SELECT t1.&ColumnName, 
            (COUNT(t1.&ColumnName)) AS COUNT_of_&ColumnName
      FROM &libname..&tblname t1
      GROUP BY t1.&ColumnName
      ORDER BY COUNT_of_&ColumnName DESC;
```

This code is working but with this code I am selecting all types of variables, however I would like to select only if a variable is CHAR.

Is there a way that I create this condition with a simple where clausule? Or do I need to create a 'if condition'? If yes, how can I create it?

Thank You!

Comment: If you can use PROC FREQ or MEANS instead you can use the automatic variable `_character_` which refers to all character values. If this is a summary of all your character values and the counts of those values, this approach will work. Replace the variables in the `table` statement with `_character_` https://gist.github.com/statgeek/e0903d269d4a71316a4e

Comment: You could also generate a dynamic list by querying sashelp.vcolumn or dictionary.column table to select all character variables.

Comment: How is the macro variable COLNAME being set?  What do want to do when COLNAME is referencing a character variable? Do you not want to create the output table or create an empty table?  Can you share the larger context of what you are doing?  Most likely you would want to filter before getting to the point of generating the code to count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SAS installation available right now but this code should work

```
data _null_;
  /*
  The relevant columns are probably named differently;
  Check the table sashelp.vcolumn what the values in COLTYPE for character variables actually are
  Don't know exactly out of my head
  */
  set sashelp.vcolumn(where=(MEMNAME eq 'MY_TABLE' and COLTYPE in ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR'))) end=eof; 
  
  attrib COLNAMES format=$1000.;
  retain COLNAMES;
  
  /*
    the following two lines concatenate all extracted column names;
    choose one of the two
  */
  /*concatenate all variable names in a string using || operator*/
  COLNAMES = compbl(COLNAMES) || ', ' || compbl(COLNAME);
  /*or via function catx*/
  colnames=catx(', ',colnames,colname);

  /*define a macro variable to hold all determined columns*/
  if eof then do;
    call symput('M_COLNAMES', compbl(COLNAMES));
  end;
run;

/*print all found columns*/
%put Character columns: &M_COLNAMES.;
```

You can then use the macro variable M_COLNAMES in your select statement.
This should give you an idea how you can do this.

Don't hesitate to ask further questions.

Comment: You might like CATX  colnames=catx(', ',colnames,colname);

Comment: I edited my answer regarding data _null_'s comment